# Problems moving 2D camera and objects in UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scene in which I have an orthographic camera that shows me a map, which I show to a ui through a raw image and a texture, what I do is to be able to move this camera through a script (which is on the camera), all that works fine, blah blah blah, the problem is that besides the camera view, I also have other objects on the ui and when I drag my finger on the objects, the camera also moves.

I was trying to solve this in different ways with "EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId)" and other things regarding "EventSystem" but it doesn't work for me, debug to know the names of the objects when I touch them and when I touch the buttons, it does return their names, but when I touch the map, it throws me a NullReferenceException. Any help, thanks.

I will leave some images so that it is understood

```
Debug.Log(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.layer);
Debug.Log(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name);
Debug.Log(EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId));
```

[image: The error when touching the map]

[image: The camera]

[image: The map]

Comment: Which language is the code you've shown in? C# or UnityScript?

Comment: Unity started to deprecate submissions containing UnityScript in 2017 so it's a good chance OP is using C#. https://blog.unity.com/community/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset

Comment: I just started using Unity two months ago, so I guess it's just C#